# Autorenew system, how to avoid multiple renew?

Tags: php, concurrency, race-condition

I provide a service where my customers can be auto-charged to renew their credits when their account reach a certain threshold. It works the same way as [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com).

Code level, it works as follows: When the user makes a query, the app decrease it's credits to one, then check if the current credits == {auto renew amount}. If it's the case, a job is sent to the Queue service to start a renew.

The test is critical here, I check for when the remains EQUALS the value of auto renew, and not when it's LOWER OR EQUAL, because in that case, an renew would be made everytime the user query the API while the first auto-renew has not been fully processed.

But I had an odd issue today. One of my customer had two renew instead of one. My first guess is that there is a race condition on the API, meaning that two request are made simultaneously, with the "remaining" credits identical, and equal to the number to auto renew, thus throwing two auto-renew.

My question here is quite simple : How can I avoid making two renew ?

The main idea is to fix the race condition issue but I don't see how, the API is written in PHP with NGinx. The server should be aware there is N requests made to the same account in order to calculate the current usage of the credits (remaining - {concurrent requests}) which seems impossible.

How can I do this?

Comment: check the renew queue before placing a new renew request

Comment: I finally had the idea. In the script that is called by the queue system, I check if the current account to renew has truly need to be renewed (that means if it's the second iteration, the test will fail). Since there is only one running script for the renewing queue, it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to only allow 1 PHP process to run the auto-charge function at any given time. The easiest way to do this is to surround your code with `flock()/fclose()`:

```
$lock = fopen("/tmp/renew", "w+");
flock($lock, LOCK_EX);

<renew code>

fclose($lock);
```

This will ensure that only 1 PHP process will be running `<renew code>` at a time. So even if 100 renew requests will come in, request #1 will run the renew code, and requests #2-#100 will stop running when then hit `flock()`. When #1 finishes, #2 will run, when #2 finishes, #3 runs, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came around with this solution :

Since the renew script is called from a queueing system (Beanstalk), and since my server only runs one instance of this renew script, I check again in the renew script if the credits needs to be renewed.

Suppose there is two call for the same account, the first one will return less credits than the auto_renew quantity, thus adding new credits.
The second run will see that there is now more credits than the auto_renew quantity, and will be ignored.

I think I closed the issue, but I prefer to give the point to @Brian with had a clever way to do it in case the script is not called from a Queueing system!.